# getting the count of a specific hashtag from twitter PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, twitter, simplexml

i am able to get all twitter posts of a specific hashtag in PHP. What now is that i want to get the total number of count for that particular hashtag.
i am using curl , SimpleXMLElement as well as twitter API search calls.
Any idea on how to get the total number of count for that specific hashtag?

```
<?php
$pagetitle = "Pull Twitter Hashtags";


function getTweets($hash_tag) {

    $url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q='.urlencode($hash_tag).'&result_type=recent' ;
    echo "<p>Connecting to <strong>$url</strong> ...</p>";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $xml = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

//If you want to see the response from Twitter, uncomment this next part out:
//echo "<p>Response:</p>";
//echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($xml)."</pre>";

    $affected = 0;
    $twelement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    foreach ($twelement->entry as $entry) {
    $text = trim($entry->title);
    $author = trim($entry->author->name);
    $time = strtotime($entry->published);
    $id = $entry->id;

    //echo count($entry->text);
    echo "<p>Tweet from ".$author.": <strong>".$text."</strong>  <em>Posted ".date('n/j/y g:i a',$time)."</em></p>";
}



return true ;
}

getTweets('#converse');


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [count()](http://uk.php.net/count)

```
$number_of_tweets = count($twelement->entry);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "all tweets" - only "all tweets in the past x hours" (maybe days).

That's the first thing any Twitter developer should know - consider tweets an infinite stream. You cannot count an infinite stream, nor can you get all of them.

To count "all tweets about #hashtag in the past hour" simply get all tweets with that hashtag from the past hour, then count them.